# Questions regarding setting up a Driver amplifier. (For example, what the "Crossing Point Adjustment"?)

Tags: amplifier, driver

In my lab, I have a fancy arbitrary waveform generator that can produce electrical pulses that are 10 nanoseconds long. Currently these signals are being sent through a driver amplifier (see [here](https://www.tek.com/en/datasheet/amplifiers-and-drivers/pspl5868-datasheet-1)). (For context: this amplifier is being used to send into an "EOM", which uses that electrical signal to reproduce it to make a laser's intensity have the same shape as provided pulse shape of the electrical signal. I can read that laser signal with a photodiode and an oscilloscope.)

All of the inputs of the amplifier are being provided by 2 multiple-output voltage powersupplies. The wiring is pretty loose and simply touching the wires very clearly changing the shape of the pulses I'm generating, so I'm going to go through and redo the wiring.

The problem is: I've only inherited this setup, so I actually don't know what voltages do what. Looking at the [spec sheet](https://download.tek.com/datasheet/PSPL5868-Datasheet-2.pdf), I see that there is a list of different voltage ranges that can be used:

[image]

Other than this, there is only a very small set of instructions and notes:
[image]

I am having some trouble interpreting what some of these things are. For example, what is the "crossing point adjust"? Crossing point of what?

Any ideas on how to choose these voltage values, or if there's like a general procedure for these kinds of things?

Comment: From your screenshot: "The PSPL5868 10.7 Gb/s modulator driver can be operated using only
three of the available 7 pins. The DC pins required for operation are 1, 3,
and 7". Have you actually encountered an issue that suggests that you need to adjust/tune the crossing point, variable gain control, or DC bias? If so, can you provide scope traces, eye diagrams, or other measurements that might help us understand what issue you're trying to solve with these adjustments?

Comment: "Have you actually encountered an issue that suggests that you need to adjust/tune the crossing point, variable gain control, or DC bias?" Sorry but I'm not yet at that stage yet, I was first asking what some of these things are first, but I suppose I can empirically see what happens on a scope.

Comment: No worries. My guess is that crossing point might tweak the input DC bias in some way, but I agree that the datasheet is rather sparse.